# What is the longest English word that starts and ends with the same letter?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-games

I've found "enterprise", which is 10 letters long. Does anyone know of any longer words that start and end with the same letter?

That letter doesn't have to be 'e', by the way. It just means that the first and last letter of the word have to be identical.

Comment: "Smiles" has a mile between the S's. (I couldn't resist.)

Comment: This is the kind of thing you should ask a computer, e.g. with a shell script you could use `egrep '^([[:lower:]])[[:lower:]]*\1$' /usr/share/dict/british-english-insane |awk '{ print length(), $0 }' |sort -n ` to filter and order a wordlist.

Comment: EXTINCTIONSPECTROPHOTOPOLERISCOPEOCCULOGRAVOGYROKYNETOMETRE

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is a very old joke usually told by (British?) schoolchildren. The answer/punchline is "Nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn...nnnn" and means that you are constipated."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Puzzling.SE, under trivia.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, while I agree that the question should have been closed immediately upon posting, what exactly is supposed to be accomplished by closing it **now**, given that it has been around for eleven years, and received six answers and 80K views? It is quite unlikely that it will be deleted.

Comment: @jsw 29 The question has resurfaced, received prominence. The actions taken are to help police the site, keep it from mediocrity, by pointing out the fact that trivia questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- achondroplasia - 14
- breadcrumb - 10
- cineangiocardiographic - 22
- deinstitutionalized - 19
- **ethylenediaminetetraacetate - 27**
- flameproof - 10
- governmentalizing - 17
- handsbreadth - 12
- interstimuli - 12
- (There is no word beginning and
  ending with J)
- kinnikinnick - 12
- lepidopterological - 18
- mesembryanthemum - 16
- nondiscrimination - 17
- obbligato - 9
- postmastership - 14
- qepiq<sup>[*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/qepiq)</sup>, qayaq<sup>[*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/qajaq)</sup> - 5
- remanufacturer - 14
- straightforwardnesses - 21
- transformationalist - 19
- unau - 4
- vav - 3
- wheelbarrow - 11
- xerox - 5
- youthfully - 10
- zuz - 3 (found on [Dictionary.Reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/zuz) and [TheFreeDictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/zuz), but not in the [Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=zuz) dictionary)

Many of these words may not feature in the English dictionary. Some are medical or technical words.

Comment: straightforwardnesses?  really???  could you use that in a sentence?

Comment: :) I was wondering the same.

However, the question was the longest words and I found these.

Comment: I mean, it seems syntactically correct... I just can't imagine any context where it would make any sense at all.

Comment: @advs89: The thing I find most appealing about your comment is the straightforwardness with which you express your disbelief.

Comment: Er...wait. I missed the pluralization. Please, forget that I said that.

Comment: Yeah, I actually had "straightforwardness" in _MY_ answer.  It was the plural that I was questioning.

Comment: I can appreciate both advs89's and dmckee's straightforwardnesses.

Comment: I was about to suggest "Zanzibar" for letter Z. Took me a while to figure out it didn't really end up with a Z. No idea how I couldn't notice at first :V

Comment: I agree with @Neil: chemical names are a "cheat" here. Couldn't we change the E to something else?

Comment: @mgkrebbs: +1 ahhhh... there we go.  So it _can_ be used in a sentence.

Answer (score 9):

Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious comes to mind.

Although some might claim the word is a bit artificial. :)

Answer (score 5):

What's your definition of "word"? Names of chemical compounds can be of any arbitrary length (and various chemical prefixes both start and end with "e", for example)...

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: granted, I guess it doesn't really matter on a CW...

Comment: @advs89 -- it's kind of the answer, in fact: under some definitions of "word", a word can be of theoretically infinite length.

Answer (score 1):

Naturalisation has 14 letters.

Answer (score 1):

straightforwardness:  19 letters
Andrianampoinimerina: 20 letters (if we're counting proper nouns)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the output of a quick-and-dirty script that I wrote (in descending order):

- supercalifragilisticexpialidocious - 34
- ethylenediaminetetraacetate - 27
- transubstantiationalist - 23
- cineangiocardiographic - 22
- labioglossopharyngeal - 21
- abetalipoproteinemia - 20
- nonindustrialization - 20
- dynamometamorphosed - 19
- plenipotentiaryship - 19
- governmentalising - 17
- metapostscutellum - 17
- rhomborectangular - 17
- hygrothermograph - 16
- improvvisatori - 14
- overlubricatio - 14
- frictionproof - 13
- killickinnick - 13
- windlestraw - 11
- xylanthrax - 10
- bumblebomb - 10
- uturuncu - 8
- qepiq - 5
- zizz - 4
- vav - 3

Here's the original output (in alphabetical order):

- abetalipoproteinemia - 20
- bumblebomb - 10
- cineangiocardiographic - 22
- dynamometamorphosed - 19
- ethylenediaminetetraacetate - 27
- frictionproof - 13
- governmentalising - 17
- hygrothermograph - 16
- improvvisatori - 14
- killickinnick - 13
- labioglossopharyngeal - 21
- metapostscutellum - 17
- nonindustrialization - 20
- overlubricatio - 14
- plenipotentiaryship - 19
- qepiq - 5
- rhomborectangular - 17
- supercalifragilisticexpialidocious - 34
- transubstantiationalist - 23
- uturuncu - 8
- vav - 3
- windlestraw - 11
- xylanthrax - 10
- youthfullity - 12
- zizz - 4

I'm such an industrious citizen, editing the good ones into the main answer.